# Uneven multicolumn table not filling up entire width. Latex

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I have a problem with a table in Latex, that i just cant get to work.
I found online that i can put a table into a multicolumn environment, to change from 4 columns to 3, and that seems to work well if i go from 4 to 2, but not 4 to 3.

I'm not sure where the problem is, but i guess I have to define the width of the table inside multicolumn somehow.

I have included the code as well as the generated table. It should hopefully be obvious how I want it to look when done correctly :)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
       \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Site 3 freeboard statistics}\\
       \hline
        Data & Mean ($\mu$) & Median & Spread ($\sigma$) \\
        \hline
        ALS mid line & 1.018 & 0.947 & 0.539\\
        ALS mid full width & 0.481 & 0.389  & 0.296 \\
        ALS at CryoSat width & 0.664 & 0.561 & 0.500\\
        Karen & 1.047 & 1.017 & 0.432 \\
        CryoSat w/o. snow & 0.200 & 0.200 & 0.080\\
        CryoSat w. snow & 0.401 & 0.401 & 0.101\\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Averaged to CryoSat resolution}\\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}{c|c|c} &  First point & Second point  \\
        \hline
        ALS mid line & 0.826 & 1.211 \\
        ALS mid full width & 0.545 & 0.413 \\
        ALS at CryoSat width & &  \\
        KAREN & 0.877 & 1.220 \\
        CryoSat w/o. snow & 0.12 & 0.28 \\
        CryoSat w. snow & 0.502 & 0.300
        \end{tabular}}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Snow statistics when fitting the in situ data only along latitude.}
    \label{tab:site2_stat}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Image of produced table. Lower table should have same width as upper table, while still have centered columns]

Comment: Why not just go for a single table with a total of 6 columns instead of repeating the first column?

Comment: Could you please make your example code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages?

Comment: @leandriis That is a good point :D could be a solution. The text just get kinda small then. And yes wil do that

Comment: What is the expected outcome? Are you looking to keep the same *first* column, yet have the rest spread out to match the upper table?

Comment: @Werner Yea i was looking for something like \multicolumn{1.5}{|c|}{<stuff>}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table I would write on the following way:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
                l *{5}{S[table-format=1.3]} }
    \toprule
    &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\makecell{Site 3\\ freeboard statistics}}
        &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Averaged to\\ 
                                        resolution}}        \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-6}
Data                    & {\makecell[t]{Mean\\ ($\mu$)}}   
                                & {\makecell[t]{Median}} 
                                        & {\makecell[t]{Spread\\ ($\sigma$)}}
                                                & {\makecell[t]{First\\ point}}
                                                        & {\makecell[t]{Second\\ point}}   \\
    \midrule
ALS mid line            & 1.018 & 0.947 & 0.539 & 0.826 & 1.211 \\
ALS mid full width      & 0.481 & 0.389 & 0.296 & 0.545 & 0.413 \\
ALS at CryoSat width    & 0.664 & 0.561 & 0.500 &       &       \\
Karen                   & 1.047 & 1.017 & 0.432 & 0.877 & 1.220 \\
CryoSat w/o. snow       & 0.200 & 0.200 & 0.080 & 0.12  & 0.28  \\
CryoSat w. snow         & 0.401 & 0.401 & 0.101 & 0.502 & 0.300 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    \caption{Snow statistics when fitting the in situ data only along latitude.}
    \label{tab:site2_stat}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- in table design comments below your question are considered
- for numbers are used `S` column type defined in the `siunitx` package
- table's vertical lines are omitted
- for horizontal lines are used rules defined in the `booktabs` package
- to my taste the suggested design of the table has more professional look

Comment: Exactly what I had in mind...

Comment: @leandriis, thank you! I have a hard time understanding why so many people jailed  data in a prison with strong bars. Obviously the flavors of what's aesthetic are very different ... :-)

Comment: Thank you that is pretty neat i must say :)

Answer (score 2):

And here is the tabular OP asks for, with fences and thick bars. As you will see, I defined three new column types, 4/10, 3/10 and 2/10 of the line width. The ‘clue’ here is the line defining the width of the second tabular:

```
\multicolumn{4}{@{}c@{}}{\begin{tabular}{|N|M|M|}
```

Here, I remove the side bearing and vertical lines from the multicolumn cell. Then the nested tabular will be as wide as the ‘main’ tabular, and it is easy to calculate the column widths.

If you use [tabularx](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) in combination with a fixed width `w`-column from [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/array), the calculation is much simpler. First, you set a fixed width column, thereafter three `X`-columns for the ‘main’ tabular and two for the nested tabular. [tabularx](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) does all the complicated maths for you. I define a `C` column, which only is a centred `X`-column. See example 2 below

**NB!** *@Zarko’s tabular is much nicer, I recommend that you build your tabulars according his recommendation*.

**Example 1 – tabular**

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{tabularx, array}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\newcolumntype{N}{wc{\dimexpr((\linewidth/10)*4-(2\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth))\relax}}
\newcolumntype{O}{wc{\dimexpr((\linewidth/10)*2-(2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth))\relax}}
\newcolumntype{M}{wc{\dimexpr((\linewidth/10)*3-(2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth))\relax}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[th!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|N|*{3}{O|}}
        \hline
       \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Site 3 freeboard statistics}\\
       \hline
        Data & Mean ($\mu$) & Median & Spread ($\sigma$) \\
        \hline
        ALS mid line & 1.018 & 0.947 & 0.539\\
        ALS mid full width & 0.481 & 0.389  & 0.296 \\
        ALS at CryoSat width & 0.664 & 0.561 & 0.500\\
        Karen & 1.047 & 1.017 & 0.432 \\
        CryoSat w/o. snow & 0.200 & 0.200 & 0.080\\
        CryoSat w. snow & 0.401 & 0.401 & 0.101\\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Averaged to CryoSat resolution}\\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{@{}c@{}}{\begin{tabular}{|N|M|M|}
         &  First point & Second point  \\
        \hline
        ALS mid line & 0.826 & 1.211 \\
        ALS mid full width & 0.545 & 0.413 \\
        ALS at CryoSat width & &  \\
        KAREN & 0.877 & 1.220 \\
        CryoSat w/o. snow & 0.12 & 0.28 \\
        CryoSat w. snow & 0.502 & 0.300
        \end{tabular}}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Snow statistics when fitting the in situ data only along latitude.}
    \label{tab:site2_stat}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Example 2 – tabularx**

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx, array}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[th!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|wc{4cm}|*{3}{C|}}
        \hline
       \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Site 3 freeboard statistics}\\
       \hline
        Data & Mean ($\mu$) & Median & Spread ($\sigma$) \\
        \hline
        ALS mid line & 1.018 & 0.947 & 0.539\\
        ALS mid full width & 0.481 & 0.389  & 0.296 \\
        ALS at CryoSat width & 0.664 & 0.561 & 0.500\\
        Karen & 1.047 & 1.017 & 0.432 \\
        CryoSat w/o. snow & 0.200 & 0.200 & 0.080\\
        CryoSat w. snow & 0.401 & 0.401 & 0.101\\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Averaged to CryoSat resolution}\\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{@{}c@{}}{{\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|wc{4cm}|C|C|}
         &  First point & Second point  \\
        \hline
        ALS mid line & 0.826 & 1.211 \\
        ALS mid full width & 0.545 & 0.413 \\
        ALS at CryoSat width & &  \\
        KAREN & 0.877 & 1.220 \\
        CryoSat w/o. snow & 0.12 & 0.28 \\
        CryoSat w. snow & 0.502 & 0.300
        \end{tabularx}}}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Snow statistics when fitting the in situ data only along latitude.}
    \label{tab:site3_stat}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. But as you say yourself @Zarko made a better table than i thought of :)

Comment: @Mathias Still, you can learn some tricks studying my solution, for example how to set fixed width columns and how to fit them between the margins. :)

Comment: Tabular in a multicolumn. +1 for out of the box thinking.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you for nice words :)